# Symfony secure login - No queries performed

Tags: symfony, authentication, doctrine-orm

I've been having trouble implementing Symfony's Security features in my project. I have configured my `Security.yaml` and created a `securityController` , my `User`class implements `userInterface` , and from what I can see on the docs I haven't missed anything out. My form renders fine, and I can input my username and password, but when I submit valid credentials it just refreshes the page. Profiler showed that no SQL queries had been made, and despite me configuring `authenticationUtils` to display errors (as per the tutorial on the docs) nothing is displayed.

### Security.yaml

```
security:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
encoders:
    App\Entity\User: sha256
providers:
    in_memory: { memory: ~ }
    main_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: username

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        # anonymous: true
        pattern: ^/$ #test
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            provider: main_db_provider

        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http_basic: true
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

        # form_login: true
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/$, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

### Security Controller

```
<?php
// src/Controller/SecurityController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{

/**
* @Route("/login", name="login")
*/
public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils    $authenticationUtils)
{
  // get the login error if there is one
  $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

  // last username entered by the user
  $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();


  return $this->render('ad-lotto-theme/login.html.twig', array(
    'last_username' => $lastUsername,
    'error'         => $error,
     ));
     }
}
```

### User class

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
* @UniqueEntity("email", message="This email is already in use.")
* @UniqueEntity("username", message="This username is already in use")
*/
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
/**
* @ORM\Column(name="roles",type="string", length=255)
*/
private $roles;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="salt",type="string", length=255)
 */
private $salt = "saltyboye";


/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="username",type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name = "password", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $registeredOn;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $referrer;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
 */
private $entries;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=3)
 */
private $currency;


 /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->registeredOn,
        $this->id,
        $this->email,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        $this->roles,
        $this->referrer,
        $this->currency,
        $this->entries,
        $this->salt));
        // see section on salt below
        // ,
}
    public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list (
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt
    ) = unserialize($serialized, array('allowed_classes' => false));
}
public function eraseCredentials()
{

}
public function getRoles()
{
    return array("ROLE_USER");
}


public function getSalt()
{
    return $this->salt;
}


public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getUsername(): ?string
{
    return $this->username;
}

public function setUsername(string $username): self
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

public function getPassword(): ?string
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function setPassword(string $password): self
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

public function getEmail(): ?string
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail(string $email): self
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

public function getRegisteredOn(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
    return $this->registeredOn;
}

public function setRegisteredOn(\DateTimeInterface $registeredOn): self
{
    $this->registeredOn = $registeredOn;

    return $this;
}

public function getReferrer(): ?interedThisWeek
{
    return $this->referrer;
}

public function setReferrer(?int $referrer): self
{
    $this->referrer = $referrer;

    return $this;
}

public function getEntries(): ?bool
{
    return $this->entries;
}

public function setEntries(bool $entries): self
{
    $this->entries = $entries;

    return $this;
}

public function setCurrency(bool $currency): self
{
    $this->currency = $currency;

    return $this;
}
public function getCurrency(): ?bool
{
    return $this->currency;
}

}
```

that salt is temporary, don't worry :) I haven't figured out how to implement SHA256 yet, but I needed to fill the field in the db :)

Comment: Am I seeing this right or your `login` route is also behind firewall?

Comment: no? I can access it without being authenticated. the `^/$` matches the `/` route *only* .

Comment: Ah, right, I knew that would not make sense... lemme have another look :)

Comment: Your serialize needs to match your unserialize.  And you need anonymous: ~ in your main firewall.  Might want to comment out the csrf stuff until you get things working.  Verify your html inputs are names _username and _password.

Comment: made those changes, html inputs are indeed _username and _password, still no request being made.

Comment: why do I need `anonymous: ~` in my main firewall? doesn't that defeat the point of having a firewall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you follow this official tutorial: [How to Build a Traditional Login Form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html)

First of all your firewall configured to only 1 URI - `/` because of regex `^/$`, so login form and other routes are not under the firewall.

Try to follow the tutorial from start to end just as it says there, make sure everything works and only then make changes.

Comment: but the setup is entirely different for using a traditional login form? They skip over a lot of steps and don't say what you need to change. I know the traditional login form tutorial does have some detail but I've read both thoroughly and can't see why this isn't working. Also I know that `^/$` will only match `/` , I did it just for debugging, because currently my site only has `/` , `/login` and `/register` set up and obviously you wouldn't want to put the registration and login forms within a firewall!

Comment: Why you think so about the login routes? Just put them under the firewall and make accessible to anonymous users by configuring the `access_control` option.

Comment: because there's no need to make it accessible to anonymous users? If everyone can access it, there's not much point putting it in a firewall

Comment: Login form should be accessible by anonymous users, no? If not what's the point of this form...

Comment: Anyway you have to place `check_path` (`/login`) under the firewall if you want to get it working. (or try to change `check_path` to `/`)

Comment: oh OK, I thought access for anonymous users was just the same as not having a firewall